# Visual Studio 2012 - %(Link.OutputFile)

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I am trying to build [Horde3d](http://horde3d.org/wiki/index.php5?title=Building_Horde3D) on windows 8 with visual studio 2012. The error that I get is very explicit but I have still no clue what I have to change. For example I can't find `%(Link.OutputFile)` anywhere

> > C:\Program Files
> >     (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V110\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets(1137,5):
> >     warning MSB8012:
> >     TargetPath(C:\horde3d\Horde3D\Samples\Chicago../../Build/Sample
> >     Chicago/Debug\Sample Chicago.exe) does not match the Linker's
> >     OutputFile property value (C:\horde3d\Horde3D\Build\Sample
> >     Chicago\Debug\Sample_Chicago.exe). This may cause your project to
> >     build incorrectly. **To correct this, please make sure that $(OutDir),
> >     $(TargetName) and $(TargetExt) property values match the value
> >     specified in %(Link.OutputFile)**. 1
>
> C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V110\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets(1139,5):
>   warning MSB8012: TargetName(Sample Chicago) does not match the
>   Linker's OutputFile property value (Sample_Chicago). This may cause
>   your project to build incorrectly. **To correct this, please make sure
>   that $(OutDir), $(TargetName) and $(TargetExt) property values match
>   the value specified in %(Link.OutputFile)**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it by myself. I used cmake to output a vs2012 project.